# NetBeans and Maven: Build dependencies upon running a project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, build, dependencies

I was wondering whether or not it is possible to tell NetBeans (I am running NetBeans 8.0.2) to build a project (let's call that "Project A") that is a dependency of another project (let's call that "Project B") whenever the second project is run.

I'll try to explain:

Project A is a library. Project B is a simple test application for said library. Ergo, once I change anything in the library (A), I need to build it before I can run/debug the test application (B). Oh, both projects are usign Maven (but I'd prefer a solution that does **not** involve Maven).

From time to time it simply happens: I forget that I have to build the library and wonder why my changes won't work (well, of course they won't, the library's changes have not yet been built).

**So my question is:** how can I tell NetBeans (I'd prefer not to use Maven for this) to always build the library when I run or debug the test application?

Hope you guys can find me an answer to this question, it's driving me crazy!

Thanks in advance, feel free to ask if I did not make everything clear.

Answer (score 0):

How to add one Maven project as a dependency of another in Netbeans:

1. Open Both Projects
2. Right-click Dependencies under Project B
3. Choose "Add Dependency ..." from pop-up menu.
4. Select the Open Projects Tab in the Dialog box.
5. Select Project A from the list.

I made a screencast video showing Netbeans working correctly with a dependant module: https://youtu.be/SOp070b3m24

In the video, mavenproject9 depends on mavenproject10. I edit a value in a class in mavenproject10 and then immediately run mavenproject9 and get the updated value.

Comment: Yes, that's true of course, but that does not actually solve my problem. As I stated in my question, the library project is already a dependency of the test project, but I need it to build whenever I run or debug the test application, so my changes to the library get compiled.

Comment: It works automatically I just tested it. I modified a dependency, ran the test program, got the new modified behaviour without me ever clicking the build for either project.

Comment: Well that's weird. I did the same thing and am not getting that kind of behavior at all. I still have to build the library manually each time.

Comment: Do you have "Compile on Save" disabled for either project? Did you edit code outside Netbeans? Is there an error that would prevent a file from compiling?

Comment: I'm sorry, but neither of the three things you suggested is actually the case. "Compile on save" is enabled for both projects, code is edited solely in NetBeands and there are no errors.I will dive into this a bit more, I guess. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I have the same problem, when debugging, changes in dependency projects are not updated. Have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can @alex try this on a simple project and either create a similar video to the one I just put a link to showing the problem or a set of steps to create projects that don't work. Probably best to post it as a new question with a link here in a comment.

Comment: I found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927448/hot-swap-with-netbeans-7-1-and-glassfish-3-1-1) a solution for this problem.